# How to echo cel value which contains specific word in Excel

Tags: excel

I have this working Excel formula which checks if cel A4 contains the number 33, 34, 36 or 39 and checks if cel V4 has a certain value. What I want is that instead of checking cel V4 the formula checks which cel between A3 and Z3 has the text EXAMPLE and then return the cel value of the cel below. So if cel V3 contains the word EXAMPLE the code returns V4, but if EXAMPLE is in H3 the code returns H4.

`=ALS(A4="33";(ALS((V4*100)>6;"G";ALS((V4*100)<-5;"S";"")));ALS(A4="34";(ALS((V4*100)>6;"G";ALS((V4*100)<-5;"S";"")));ALS(A4="36";(ALS((V4*100)>7;"G";ALS((V4*100)<0;"S";"")));ALS(A4="39";(ALS((V4*100)>7;"G";ALS((V4*100)<0;"S";"")))))))`

Can anyone tell me if it's possible and if so, how?

**EDIT:**

The word EXAMPLE is somewhere between cel A3 and Z4 and the could should return A4, B4, C4 etc. depending on in which cel the word EXAMPLE is. So if EXAMPLE is in V3 the formula should return V4.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If the cell you are checking in your formula contains text (EXAMPLE), your formula will return a #VALUE! error.  Also, you write you are checking if A4 contains certain **numbers**; but your formula is checking for text strings:  **"34"** is NOT the same as **34**

Comment: I made a mistake. The formula should check between cel A3 and Z3 for the word EXAMPLE and should return the letter of the cel and then row 4, so if EXAMPLE is in V3 the formula should return V4. I'm sorry I wasn't clear in the first place. @Ron Rosenfeld. "34" is the right way for my Excel-sheet. I found out 34 without ("") didn't work.

Comment: @edow Are you certain the contents of A4 is a number?  And not a text string that looks like a number?

Comment: I think it just looks like a number indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ADDRESS(4,MATCH("EXAMPLE",A4:Z4,0),4)
```

Comment: See my edited question. I made a mistake when asking my question.

Comment: @edow Just change the formula to look for EXAMPLE in A3:Z3

Comment: Thank you. Should I just copy and paste this where V4 is now in the formula or how should I do this exactly?

Comment: Because I work with the Dutch Excel version I changed the formula to this: `=ADRES(4;VERGELIJKEN("HSP1";$A$3:$Z$3;0);4)` and it works great. The only problem now is that when I copy the code to the cels below V4 (for example) doesn't change to V5, V6 etc. How can I handle that?

Comment: So for the formulas below, is the formula supposed to stil perform the match in row 3, i.e. so it will always be "V_(somenumber)"?

Comment: The formula `=ADRES(4;VERGELIJKEN("EXAMPLE";$A$3:$Z$3;0);4)` gives T4 if EXAMPLE is in cel T3. That's ok, but when I copy the formula to the cels below it should output T4, T5, t6 etc. So, he should always check in row 3 for the word EXAMPLE, but the output should change.

Comment: =ADDRESS(3+ROWS($1:1),MATCH("EXAMPLE",$A$3:$Z$3,0),4)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Works great! Now I only need to figure out how to add this the my first code from my question. I think it should be somethinh like `(ADDRESS(3+ROWS($1:1),MATCH("EXAMPLE",$A$3:$Z$3,0),4))` so the whole formula within () without the = sign and then replace all the V4's with this formula?

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure as I don't really know what your first formula is supposd to be doing. Imagine it could be simplfied though...

Comment: The formula checks if A4 is 33 and if the value in V4 (or some other cel where the new formula is for) is >6% then the output is G. If is <-5% the output is S otherwise the output is "" (empty). When A4 is 34, 36 or 39 there're other rules.